# how to prevent over typing

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a simple chat application in c++. And it works but, If someone enters something while someone else is typing. It like writes over what they were typing. I linked pictures as examples below.

The code I am using for the client and the server can be found here:

[Client](https://github.com/topkiller/networking/blob/master/Client.cpp)

[Server](https://github.com/topkiller/networking/blob/master/Server.cpp)

Pictures:

Before
[image]
After
[image]

Comment: This really has nothing to do with sockets and/or winsock -- it's purely about displaying things on screen.

Comment: If it has not become clear yet, this is far from simple. If you are doing this just as learning excercise, do not bother... Just print extra newline before and after text from other side, and be done with it. If you are doing it for real chat app, better do GUI app, especially on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to set a flag when the user first starts typing a line of text -- then if you receive data from the network while that flag is set, simply queue up the received data in some local data structure (i.e. don't print it yet) until the local user presses return.  When the local user presses return, then you would print out all the data that you had queued up while he was typing, and unset the flag.

Of course that approach has several disadvantages:

- If the local user enters some text and never presses return, he'll never see any incoming remote text.  That could be a problem e.g. if the user presses space and walks away.
- The cin/stdin functionality in C/C++ usually work on a per-line basis, and you would need to set the terminal to raw/non-canonical mode to get it to report when the local user has entered just a character (rather than buffering up characters until the local user pressed return, and then reporting the whole line of text to your program at once)

The other approach would be to keep the local user's text and the remote user's text in physically separate areas (e.g. top and bottom halves of the window, like many chat programs do).  To do that will require more control than the vanilla C/C++ stdin/stdout/cin/cout API gives you; you'd need to either create a GUI window (using Win32 or Qt or some other GUI API) with two separate text-widgets, or if you want to keep everything inside an MS-DOS window, you might uses something like [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net) to implement that.

Either of those options will be non-trivial, though -- they will likely take more time and effort to implement than the rest of your chat application.  If it was me, and the chat application was only a learning exercise, I'd be temped to simply document the current behavior as a "known limitation" and not worry about fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

Jeremy's post was pretty thorough. I'll add another option that is available to you: Keep track of the character the user who is typing has input, until he finally presses ENTER. That way, when the remote user enters text all you have to do is this:

Write an appropriate number of backspace characters ('\b') to the terminal (i.e. as many as the length of the text the local user has typed), then output the new incoming line of text, and then output all the characters the local user had typed before. Then continue as normal.

It will look as if the new incoming text "slides" into place.

Comment: As asker seems to be using windows, simplest way to achieve char-based input is to use `getch()` or `getche()` from conio.h: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Comment: @hyde: Which, of course, wouldn't help the O.P. as the problem is how to "overwrite" text that's currently displayed on screen. Not how to read input.

Comment: reading user input char-by-char is required by your answer, is it not? How else can you re-print typed chars?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <Conio.h>
#include <mutex> // C++11, if not C++11 find your own mutex

std::vector<char> inputBuffer;
std::mutex inputGuard;
struct Locker {
  std::mutex* m;
  Locker(std::mutex& m_):m(&m_) { m->lock(); }
  void release() { if (m) m->unlock(); m = 0; }
  ~Locker() { release(); }
}
void AddToInputBuffer( char c ) {
  Locker lock(inputGuard);
  inputBuffer.push_back(c);
  printf("%c",c);
}
std::string FinishInputBuffer() {
  Locker lock(inputGuard);
  std::string retval( inputBuffer.begin(), inputBuffer.end() );
  inputBuffer.clear();
  printf("\n");
  return retval;
}
void OverlappedPrintln( std::string s ) {
  Locker lock(inputGuard);
  for (int i = 0; i < inputBuffer.size(); ++i) {
    printf("%c", 8 /*backspace*/);
  }
  printf("%s\n", s.c_str());
  for (int i = 0; i < inputBuffer.size(); ++i) {
    printf("%c", inputBuffer[i]);
  }
}

std::string readCharactersFromUser() {
  // TODO: Handle exiting
  while( int input = getch() ) {
    if (input == '\n') {
      return FinishInputBuffer();
    AddToInputBuffer(input);
  }
}
```

Now, replace `cin.getline(message, 256);` with `std::string message = readCharactersFromuser()`, then check the length of the `string` before doing `(message[0] == 's' && message[1] == 'a' && message[2] == 'y' && message[3] == ' '` that.

Elsewhere in the program, where you do `printf`, instead build a `std::string` and call `OverlappedPrintln` with it.

The effect of this is that when you want to print something out, you lock a mutex, backspace over the user input, print out the message, do a newline, then print out the text you backspaced over, and release your mutex.  The mutex isn't needed in 99% of situations, especially with modern computer speed, but it is good practice.

The above code was not tested or compiled.  Nor is it of the highest quality.

The choice of non-echoing get character was because I cannot read from user input in a lock, and asynchronously echoing to the output might cause garbled text.  So I read without echo, then echo within the mutex, such that `inputBuffer` always contains the characters that the user has both typed and I've echoed to the screen.

This is an implementation of @NikBougalis 's answer.